# Efficent way to copy and paste a line

Tags: emacs

To copy and paste a line i use the following method

```
C-a - beginning of line

#save the line to kill-ring using kill-line(this is faster than marking,
# move to end of line and C-w)
C-k - kill-line
C-/ - undo kill-line 

# move point to required line
C-p or C-n or C-s (search for the nearest line where the paste must be done)

C-y # paste the line
```

Is there more efficent method than this. In vim just type **yy**, navigate and **p** does the job

Comment: This is more a SuperUser question.

Comment: With evil-mode, just use the default vim keybindings. http://wikemacs.org/index.php/Evil

Comment: @ceejayoz I would say it's more of an emacs.stackexchange question

Answer (score 2):

Use `kill-whole-line` instead of <kbd>C-a</kbd><kbd>C-k</kbd>. It's mapped to <kbd>C-S-backspace</kbd> by default.

Comment: According to emacs -Q, `kill-whole-line` is defaultly bound to `C-S-backspace`

Comment: @MrBones: Thanks for confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

With evil-mode, just use the default vim keybindings.http://wikemacs.org/index.php/Evil

Otherwise, `M-w` (kill-ring-save) saves the region. If we want to copy the current line if no region is selected:

```
(put 'kill-ring-save 'interactive-form
 '(interactive
   (if (use-region-p)
       (list (region-beginning) (region-end))
     (list (line-beginning-position) (line-beginning-position 2)))))
(put 'kill-region 'interactive-form
 '(interactive
   (if (use-region-p)
       (list (region-beginning) (region-end))
     (list (line-beginning-position) (line-beginning-position 2)))))
```